# Problems creating confusion matrix, using pandas crosstab and pandas_ml ConfusionMatrix

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

Trying to compare "actual" values with "predicted" values, for a Sequential model.  The "actual" values are contained in a dataframe, while the "predicted" values are an array generated by the model.predict function.  I get a lot of mismatches, and various errors, including "Data must be 1-dimensional", "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 1406", etc.
I have tried various combinations of pd.values, pd.values.tolist(), trying to make an array of the dataframe, etc.

```
train_set_split, test_set_split = split_train_test(churn_no_NA, 0.2)
train_set_withID = train_set_split
test_set_withID = test_set_split
X_train = train_set_split.drop("customerID", axis=1)
y_train = train_set_split[["Churn"]]
X_test = test_set_split.drop("customerID", axis=1)
y_test = test_set_split[["Churn"]]
...
model = Sequential()
...
y_predict = model.predict_classes(X_test)
...
confusion_matrix = ConfusionMatrix(y_test, y_predict)
print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % confusion_matrix)
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Have you checked the shape of the both actual and predicted lists?

Comment: Yes, they're both (1406,1).

Comment: Print down both lists or pd.series and check whether there are any list of lists.
Also check this link once: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95209/how-can-i-interpret-sklearn-confusion-matrix

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!  What worked for me was to construct a dataframe from the 2 "lists", and then pass each column to the ConfusionMatrix, as "x" and "y".